# ASP.NET MVC3, Html.TextAreaFor without encoding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I use the Html.TextAreaForwithout encoding it?
I know it's a security risk but I have a separate class that sanitizes any text.

Example:

@Html.TextAreaFor(model =>model.PostBodyText, 10, 100, 1)

I'm planning to use it with TinyMCE.

Regards
RaVen

**UPDATE**
I'm using the new Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to roll your own:

```
<textarea cols="100" id="PostBodyText" name="PostBodyText" rows="10">
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.PostBodyText)
</textarea>
```

Of course in terms of security this could be very dangerous as your site is now vulnerable to XSS attacks. So the question is why having a separate class that sanitizes all the text when you can simply rely on the HTML helpers to do the job for you?

Comment: Yeah I know but I'm filtering out any javascript tags...  I only allow some safe html tags.  But yeah TinyMCE may cause a security flaw.  Again Thanks very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option you might wanna use ValidateInput as described [here](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/08/ValidateInputAttributeASPNETMVCPotentiallyDangerousRequestFormValues.aspx). An example in MVC style would be:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Method(){
     return View()
}

[ValidateInput(false)]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Method(){
    // your stuff here
    RedirectToAction("index"); // or something 
}
```

I think that is more the MVC way to go. Now your controller tells you there is a security issue in that controller method. Your view can be any normal view using html helpers etc. Note that this enables all sorts of input, not filtered. **It will work with TinyMCE though**.

//edit

woops I see you need to add

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

to webconfig as well in new versions of MVC. Guess it might not be the way to go.

Comment: This is exactly correct.
[ValidateInput(false)] will allow HTML to be posted in your form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[AllowHtml]` on the model property. As I learned in [In ASP.NET MVC 3, how do I get at the model using Razor Syntax in a Create() View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864824/in-asp-net-mvc-3-how-do-i-get-at-the-model-using-razor-syntax-in-a-create-vie).