# I don't understand the answer to "ASP.NET MVC3, Html.TextAreaFor without encoding?"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In "[ASP.NET MVC3, Html.TextAreaFor without encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245431/asp-net-mvc3-html-textareafor-without-encoding)"

Darin Dimitrov had the answer, but I can't make it work.

Probably because I'm confused about what the @model statement at the top of a strictly typed View means.

My statement is:

```
@model TestTinyMCE.Models.TestBlog
```

When I type in his answer:

```
You will need to roll your own:
<textarea cols="100" id="PostBodyText" name="PostBodyText" rows="10"> 
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.PostBodyText) 
</textarea>
```

It fails because Model is null.

How do I associate Model with the model my View is using?

I'm in a Create() view, btw, if that matters. This will also have to work in the Edit(int id) View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show us your Controller code?

It should look like:

```
using TestTinyMCE.Models;

public class Mycontroller : Controller 
{
   public ActionResult Create() 
   {
      return View(new TestBlog());
   }

   public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
   {
      var model = new TestBlog(); 

      // Fill the model value with the entity from your datastore

      return View(model);
   }
}
```

You must set the model of your View in your controller actions. This way, you won't receive a null value in your Razor view.

In the view, I would write this:

```
@model TestTinyMCE.Models.TestBlog

<textarea cols="100" id="PostBodyText" name="PostBodyText" rows="10"> 
    @Html.Raw(Model.PostBodyText) 
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, I had been using the auto-generated Controller which called the Create View with no arguments.